# Creating Composite key in ApplicationDbContext using fluent api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am getting data from an NBA API and in order to write the data to my database I need to create the DB object of PlayerGame with composite keys PlayerID and GameID I tried using two [key][column=] tags to define this but when attempting to add the migration I was given the error need to use fluent api. so after some googling I came up with the following code and now upon attempting a migration I am given the error message The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'. I'm guessing it has to do with ApplicationDbCOntext inheriting from IdentityDbContext but I really have no clue what to do at this point. Please help!!

I have a class Player Game

```
public class PlayerGame
{

    [Required]
    public int PlayerID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey ("PlayerID")]
    public Player Player { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public int GameID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey ("GameID")]
    public Game Game { get; set; }
```

and DB Context

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{

    public DbSet<Player> Player {get; set; }

    public DbSet<Game> Game { get; set; }

    public DbSet<PlayerGame> PlayerGame { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<PlayerGame>()
            .HasKey(pg => new { pg.PlayerID, pg.GameID });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually very simple. Move the call to base method below your custom logic and it should work.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<PlayerGame>()
        .HasKey(pg => new { pg.PlayerID, pg.GameID });

    base.OnModelCreating(builder); // <-- move this line to bottom
}
```

You should finish all your custom configurations before calling the base method. The base method is what is throwing that error

Comment: I have a class PlayerBet that was attached to PlayerGame How would I go about getting the PlayerGame object in PlayerBet via the composite key?

Comment: Its hard to give a comprehensive answer without the full code but maybe somehting like this `context.PlayerGame.Include(pg => pg.Bet).Find(playerID, gameID })`. find gets the data and the include means it will be loaded along with PlayerGame and accepts the parameters in order you set them. Or you could do this `context.PlayerGame.Where(pg => pg.PlayerID == playerID && pg.GameID == gameID).Select(pg => pg.PlayerBet }).FirstOrDefault()`. Both has async versions so use them if possible